# Counting number of occurrence of a column

Tags: php, mysql

So if my title is a bit confusing which I believe it is. And by the way I'm using medoo API for my sql so that's just a small information just so you don't get confused by the following examples.

***EXAMPLE TABLE***

```
+----+------------+----------------+-------------+
| id | playerName | infractionType | infractedBy |
+----+------------+----------------+-------------+
|  1 | Alpha      | ET1            | Admin       |
|  2 | Alpha      | ET1            | Admin       |
|  3 | Alpha      | ET1            | Admin       |
|  4 | Delta      | ET1            | Admin       |
|  5 | Echo       | ET1            | Admin       |
|  6 | Echo       | ET1            | Admin       |
|  7 | Delta      | ET1            | Admin       |
|  8 | Alpha      | ET1            | Admin       |
+----+------------+----------------+-------------+
```

Okay so let's go over the basics. If you do a foreach loop like this:

```
foreach ($medoo->query("SELECT * FROM table1) as $entry) {
    echo $entry['playerName'];
}
```

So as you should know that will print out ALL playerName. Now what I want is to print out the occurence of the playerName and echo that out. So for a non-ordered print, the code would be somewhere along these lines:

```
foreach ($medoo->query("SELECT DISTINCT playerName FROM table1) as $entry) {
    echo $entry['playerName'];
    echo $medoo->count("infractions", ["playerName" => $entry['playerName']);
}
```

HOWEVER AS STATED "THIS IS NOT ORDERED" what I want is to order it which I have no clue as to how to do so. I've looked all over google saw the 'count()' sql command but it's basically useless to me as far as I see it.

**What I want to Know**

- Is there a SQL STATEMENT that will meet my needs? If so what is it.
- If it's not possible with SQL STATEMENT then is it possible to create a sort using php? (I believe so personally).

**Current Code**

```
foreach ($GoldenData->query("SELECT DISTINCT playerName FROM infractions") as $player) {
foreach ($GoldenData->query("SELECT COUNT(playerName) AS playerName FROM infractions WHERE playerName = '" . $player['playerName'] ."' ORDER BY COUNT(playerName) DESC") as $infracted) {
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>";
echo $player['playerName'];
echo "</td>";
echo "<td>";
echo $infracted['playerName'];
echo "</td>";
echo "<tr>";
}   
}
```

**What I want EXPLAINED**

> This is also in the comments but I'm just adding it here so other people could see it better.

So the idea is basically to sort by count of TOTAL INFRACTIONS and order that by descending order (Most to least). Now the problem is the fact that I don't have the column 'totalInfractions' which I do not want to add not unless there is NO OTHER WAY of doing this without the column. So the question is if it's possible to do this without adding the 'totalInfractions' column or if there is another way of doing it through the means of other SQL STATEMENTS or PHP Functions.

---

If you are not understanding something please do let me know and I will try and clear it up. I do understand what I'm asking for is a bit confusing.

Comment: i dont understand what output you expect

Comment: I find your question confusing. Do you want "SELECT playerName, COUNT(playerName) AS occurence FROM table1 GROUP BY playerName ORDER BY occurence DESC'?

Comment: @Dagon Output is basically totalInfractions and name of player in order of descending order.

Comment: @markdwhite No. If you look at the my current code it shows that I want to sort by the number of infractions from most to least which is basically (desc) order. I thought of a way of doing it but that requires adding another field and that is totalInfractions column which I don't want to add if there is another cleaner way of doing so.

Comment: @RepeaterCreeper - so...change 'AS occurence...ORDER BY occurence DESC' to 'AS infractions...ORDER BY infractions DESC'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you want to accomplish...

I ran this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(id), playerName from Example group by playerName;
```

And the output was this:

```
+-----------+------------+

| count(id) | playername |

+-----------+------------+

|         4 | Alpha      |

|         2 | Delta      |

|         2 | Echo       |

+-----------+------------+
```

What we are doing is COUNTing each ID (since every entry represents a single infraction, this is equivalent to counting the number of infractions), and then GROUPing by playerName so that we get a total for each player.  Is this close to what you are trying to do?

I apologize for the poorly formatted copy/pasted results table, I'm not sure how to get it to look nicer.

If, in the future, you add more infractionTypes, you might want something like this: 
SELECT COUNT(id), playername, infractionType from example GROUP BY infractionType, playername;

which will yield results like this:

```
+-----------+------------+----------------+

| count(id) | playername | infractionType |

+-----------+------------+----------------+

|         3 | Alpha      | ET1            |

|         1 | Delta      | ET1            |

|         1 | Alpha      | ET2            |

|         1 | Delta      | ET2            |

|         2 | Echo       | ET2            |

+-----------+------------+----------------+
```

Comment: The query was not specifically correct. But it did give me the basic statement and all I had to do was to basically edit the query you gave me and make it `SELECT playerName from infractions GROUP BY playerName ORDER BY COUNT(playerName) DESC` . But either way thanks for giving me an idea of how to do it. Never expected it to be that simple, I guess I was just over complicating things again.